# Can I dynamically add a field to FormType form?

Tags: symfony

I have a PostType form that extends AbstractType. In controller I'd like to add a field to it if certain condition is met. Can I do this somehow or is there another best practice on modifying FormTypes in controllers?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by using [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html).

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the solution I need.

Comment: How did you manage to do it ? Can't see how events can help here ?

Answer (score 7):

Let say you have a Form of type **FileType** as follow:

```
<?php
namespace EventFlowAnalyser\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class FileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'file';
    }
}
```

You can use it in your controller like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FileType(), $document);
```

Where **$document** is an object containing one field (*name*).
Now, if you need to add a field to the form object in another function, you can extend the **FileType** to add the field you need; for example if you want to edit the name field but want still to keep track of the previous state lets add an **original_name** field.

```
<?php
namespace EventFlowAnalyser\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use EventFlowAnalyser\Form\EventListener\EditFileFieldSubscriber;

class FileEditType extends FileType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->add('original_name', 'hidden', array('mapped' => false));
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the extended form like that:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FileEditType(), $document);
```

And modify the value of the field like that:

```
$form->get('original_name')->setData($document->name);
```

I hope this will help somenone :o)

Answer (score 5):

Sure You can add fields dynamically using Collection Type in form.
See the below link, this will helps you how to make fields dynamically.

[Link1: Dynamic Field in Symfony2](http://sf.khepin.com/2011/08/basic-usage-of-the-symfony2-collectiontype-form-field/)

[Link2: Form Collection in symfony2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Hope these two links helps you.
Happy coding..

Comment: collections? I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add a boolean option to your form, and set it in your controller. This way you would have a clean M(V)C separation.

Comment: This might be a good option. I just wonder why there is no ->add() function available in FormType

Comment: Hi David, they appear to have added that in 2.2 http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html#method_add