# Symfony 2 - Add Field to

Tags: symfony

In my controller, I have:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ResetPassword());
```

ResetPassword is an AbstractType class with it's own buildForm() method that I'm using to ->add some fields as is.

In my controller, I want to be able to add another field to the form before I display it.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ResetPassword())->add('test');
```

This generates an error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Form::add() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface, string given
```

Comment: Check this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337169/can-i-dynamically-add-a-field-to-formtype-form

Answer (score 3):

There is a much better approach that let you keep working in a clean MVC structure. So, better is to use "Form events" to [dynamically generate your forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html).

For example, by adding an event subscriber to your Form, you delegate the creation of your fields to that Subscriber. You can then add the fields you want inside your subscriber according to your "EventType".

[Adding An Event Subscriber To A Form Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class)

[How to Dynamically Generate Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html)